# Diameter of inner parallel body

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-polytopes

Let's say I have a convex polytope $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interior.

Let $\mathcal{P}=\bigcap_{i=1}^mH_i$ for some halfspaces $H_i$ and let $d=diam(\mathcal{P})=\sup\{\|x-y\|:x,y\in \mathcal{P}\}$ be the diameter of the polytope.

If I define a new polytope $\mathcal{P}_{\lambda}$ by translating all facets (the $n-1$ dimensional faces) of $\mathcal{P}$ a distance $\lambda$ in their inward normal direction, how does the diameter $d_\lambda=diam(\mathcal{P}_\lambda)$ relate to the diameter $d$ of the original polytope $\mathcal{P}$, the parameter $\lambda$, and the dimension $n$ (if it depends on $n$)?

We can assume that $\lambda$ is small enough so that $\mathcal{P}_\lambda$ has no empty interior.

I have found that $\mathcal{P}_\lambda$ is called an "inner parallel body" of $\mathcal{P}$.

Anyone got an idea?

EDIT: I found that the inradius $r_\lambda$ of $\mathcal{P}_\lambda$ (that is the radius of the maximum ball inside $\mathcal{P}_\lambda$) is $r_\lambda=r-\lambda$ where $r$ is the inradius of the original polytope $\mathcal{P}$.

Is a similar relation true for the circumradius (i.e the radius of the minimal ball containing the polytope)?

Comment: In the first sentence of the question, $n$ is the dimension of the ambient space $\mathbb R^n$. In the second sentence, it's the number of half-spaces $H_i$. Those should surely be different.

Comment: Couldn't $d_{\lambda}$ be arbitrarily small? If you think about a really skinny rhombus in the plane, then $\frac{d}{d\lambda} d_\lambda |_{\lambda = 0}$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes thanks, I changed it now.

Comment: @WillieWong I want to know how $d_\lambda$ changes with $\lambda$ and the original diameter $d$.

Comment: @jonatan: my point is that you cannot just write $d_{\lambda}$ as a function of $d$ and $\lambda$. You need more information about the original polytope.

Comment: Re: your edit. For the inradius, the reason that formula works is because the maximum ball inside $P$ is tangent to the faces of $P$. And hence moving in the direction normal to the faces is moving in the central direction to the ball. For the circumscribed balls, the ball will be touching your polytope on the vertices and not on the faces. So you don't have the same formula. As I suggested in my previous comment, draw yourself a skinny rhombus and compute a few examples. You will see there is no general formula that depends only on $d$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: @WillieWong Okey, any idea of what kind of information about the original polytope that could be used to obtain a bound on the change in the diameter?